# Call up variables with inputs, does that works in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, reflection, cin, cout

I am a hobby programmer. I'm asking for help, because I'm wondering if you can call a variable which is equivalent to the input without the code snippet looking like that:

```
std::string exampleVariable = "Hello";

std::string exampleInput;
std::cin >> exampleInput;

if(exampleInput == "exampleVariable")
     std::cout << exampleVariable;
```

I want to get my code so far to have that structure:

### **`Input(Example)` `=>` `Output(variable named Example)`**

Can I get some help here? I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not directly possible in c++. You'd have to use some other way of mapping strings  to values.

Comment: The closest you can get (assuming `string` is `std::string`) is `if (exampleInput == "exampleVariable") std::cout << exampleVariable;`  (note the double quotes).   There is not however a way in C++ to implicitly map the contents of a string (say, read from a file, and interpret) to the name of a variable.   If you want such a capability, you have to implement the machinery yourself (or use a third-party library) since it isn't supplied implicitly by the language or compiler.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve something similiar with [`std::unoredered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Also what you want to do is kind of what a debgger does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, you'd use a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` for that. This is a key-value map, where both are strings.

E.g.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> variables;
variables["Hi"] = "Hello";
std::string exampleInput;
std::cin >> exampleInput;
std::cout << variable[exampleInput];
```

It's safe to use a key that's not yet in the map, you'll get a default value (e.g. an empty string).

You can also have other key types than string, as long as they can be sorted, and other value types. `int` works perfectly well for both.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a macro, this allows you to check the variable name, you would still need to store the variable name in a separate variable to compare it with the name of the `Example` variable.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NPVmMaVaUGCZmATg)

```
#include <iostream>

#define printVar(var, name) (std::cout << (#var == name ? var : "No match"))

int main()
{   std::string varName;
    std::string Example = "Hello";
    std::cin >> varName;
    printVar(Example, varName);      
}
```

Input:

```
Example
```

Output:

```
Hello
```